# How do I get back a small HTTPS Everywhere icon in the Firefox toolbar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, toolbar, https-everywhere

With an upgrade just now, the HTTPS Everywhere icon is now roughly twice the height (and width) that it used to be. The result of this is a much thicker gray bar all the way around the browser toolbar, because none of the other controls are this size.

**How do I get the icon/button back to the ~16 pixels height** that everything else is able to fit within, and it was able to fit within until just now?

I have tried removing and adding back the button from/to the toolbar, restarted Firefox, have looked through the options both in the HTTPS Everywhere GUI as well as in about:config (filtered for `everywhere`, `size` and `toolbar`, and saw nothing that looked relevant). The [EFF's FAQ](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq) seems to not even be updated to reflect this release, as [What do the different colors for rulesets in the toolbar menu mean?](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq#faq-What-do-the-different-colors-for-rulesets-in-the-toolbar-menu-mean?) still describes the old toolbar button.

Comment: Hmm. Have you restarted your browser? I just installed the new version of https everywhere, restarted the browser, and have a new icon `S` in a blue cube. It is the same size as the other icons and look like the icon at the top of https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere (the one in the banner). In short everything looks and behaves as expected ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Looks like a bug that has now been fixed, but might not have been pushed to everyone just yet. See my self-answer. (And yes, I did restart the browser. Might as well add that to the question, too.)

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 5.2.0 and I don't see the bug https://i.imgur.com/wTMnlwv.png I guess I'm lucky :)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's a bit odd. Maybe there's something about my settings that caused this to show up, but doesn't for you. Might explain why it wasn't caught in testing; you'd think that, if it affected everyone equally, it would have been caught real quick during testing. *To your screenshot:* That's decidedly *not* what it looked like to me after the upgrade to 5.2.0.

Comment: I have a lot of other extensions loaded. The most obvious ones that could affect the display are Classic Theme Restorer and maybe Classic Toolbar Buttons. Glad you fixed it anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in HTTPS Everywhere 5.2.1. Looks like it's only an issue with version 5.2.0, and only for some people. You can check which version you have installed by going into Tools > Add-Ons > Extensions, locating the HTTPS Everywhere entry in the list, and checking the version number attached to it. If the version number isn't shown, use the *More* link to get to the details page where the version number is shown.

Until the updated version is approved by the Mozilla gatekeepers, you can download 5.2.1 [directly from the EFF's web site](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/) (look under the *Recent releases* heading). Simply clicking on the file name will download and allow you to install the updated version.

According to the [change log](https://www.eff.org/files/Changelog.txt), this version is merely:

> Firefox 5.2.1
>
> - Bugfix release: fix CSS to prevent large icons